# Drop a part of a timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to drop a part of a time stamp.

Example:

```
2014-02-22 21:30:40.000000
```

to

```
2014-02-22
```

What is the quickest way to do it with redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to a date:

```
timestamp_col::date
```

Or use `date_trunc()`:

```
date_trunc('day', timestamp_col)
```